# Noob, creating string method's indexof and substring

Tags: string, methods, substring, indexof

As an assignment we are supposed to create methods that copy what string methods do. We are just learning methods and I understand them, but am having trouble getting it to work.
given: 
`private String st = "";`

```
public void setString(String p){
        st = p;
    }

    public String getString(){
        return st;
    }
```

I need to create `public int indexOf(char index){}`, and `public String substring(int start, int end){}` I've succesfuly made charAt, and equals but I need some help. We are only allowed to use String methods charAt(), and length(), and + operator. No arrays or anything more advanced either. This is how I'm guessing you start these methods:

```
public int indexOf(char index){
        for(int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++){
            return index;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String substring(int start, int end){
        for(int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++){

        }
        return new String(st + start);
    }
```

thanks!

here's my two working methods:

```
public boolean equals(String index){
        for(int a = 0; a < index.length() && a < st.length(); a++){
            if(index.charAt(a) == st.charAt(a) && index.length() == st.length()){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public char charAt(int index){
        if(index >= 0 && index <= st.length() - 1)
            return st.charAt(index);
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your `indexOf` method, you're on the right track.  You'll want to modify the code in the loop.  Since you're looping through the whole String, and you only have two methods available, which will help you most to get the characters from the String?  Look to your other methods (`equals` and `charAt`) to see how you did them, it might give a hint. Remember, you want find a single character in your String and print out the index in which you found it.

For your `substring` method what you need to do is get all the characters that are represented beginning at `start` index and go up until `end` index.  A loop is a good start, but you will need a base `String` to hold your progress in (you will need an empty String).  The beginning and end point of your loop need a looking at.  For `substring`, you want to get everything starting at `start` and everything before `end`.  For instance, if I do the following:

```
String myString = "Racecar";
String sub = myString.substring(1, 4);
System.out.println(sub);
```

I should get the output `ace`.

I would give you the answer, but I think helping guide your reasoning will give you more benefit.  Enjoy your assignment!

Comment: Thanks a lot! figured out index of was way easier than I tried to make it, I found trying to translate java to English and writing out what I need to do a good method at solving, thanks for not just giving me the answer

Comment: Not a problem!  Glad I could help.